# Configure switch between sources in GNOME

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop-environment, gnome-shell, desktop-shortcuts

I'm using GNOME `3.28.0` (in Arch Linux). I do also use two languages, so I constantly switch back and forth between those.

I'm trying to configure the shortcut(s) to **switch between sources** – inside `Settings > Devices > Keyboard`, but so far, I'm unable to use the ones that I would like: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> – and if possible, disable the shortcut to `Switch to previous input source` (since I only use two languages).

The default ones are: <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Any clues?

---

**UPDATE**

I tried to set it up "manually" using `dconf Editor` and the "key" `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source`...but for some reason it doesn't like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>. I even restarted the system just in case.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured this one out.

I was trying different shortcut combinations by changing this "key" `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source` – inside `dconf Editor`.

The correct combination value in order to use (the left) <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> was: `['<Alt>Shift_L']`.

[image]

Comment: Still working as of 2021, thanks !